# Resizing browser window in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In my Flex page I have a link that navigates to different webpage and I want to control the size of that child webpage. For resizing, I am using JavaScript command within my ActionScript. Here is the ActionScript code:

```
private function openLinkEvent():void{
    var baseUrl:String ="https://localhost:8080/someWebsite?customerName="customer.custName;

    var jscommand:String ="window.open(baseUrl,'win','height=280,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');";       
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);"); 
    navigateToURL(url, "_self");
}
```

I have 2 issues in this code:

1. If I do it with above mentioned way, new window is not opening and Flex page is showing error  "baseUrl is undefined". Why I am not able to pass variable for my url instead of passing the url directly in window.open method?
2. If I directly pass the value of my baseURL("https://localhost:8080/someWebsite?customerName="customer.custName;) in window.open, it is taking value of customerName as customer.custName while it should take the real value of a customer saved in the session.

Just to clarify, when I pass baseUrl in following way, my application is working absolutely fine.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(baseUrl))
```

But above command is not sufficient if I want to re-size the browser window. That is why I am using JS command integrated with ActionScript.

Answer (score 3):

> If I do it with above mentioned way, new window is not opening and
>   flex page is showing error  "baseUrl is undefined". Why I am not able
>   to pass variable for my url instead of passing the url directly in
>   window.open method?

Well, baseUrl the variable is defined, however you are not using when creating your jsCommand.  You are using a string entitled baseUrl; not the varibale.

This is what you have:

```
var jscommand:String ="window.open(baseUrl,'win','height=280,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');";
```

This is probably what you want:

```
var jscommand:String ="window.open('" + baseUrl + "','win','height=280,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');";
```

Use string concatenation to create your jscommand string. so that the resulting value for jscommand is this:

```
window.open('https://localhost:8080/someWebsite?customerName=something','win','height=280,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
```

Instead of this:

```
window.open(baseUrl,'win','height=280,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

> If I directly pass the value of my
>   baseURL("https://localhost:8080/someWebsite?customerName="customer.custName;)
>   in window.open, it is taking value of customerName as
>   customer.custName while it should take the real value of a customer
>   saved in the session.

Well, it is odd that you're missing the concatenation operator when creating your baseURL.  Add the + between your string and the `customer.custName`:

```
var baseUrl:String ="https://localhost:8080/someWebsite?customerName=" + customer.custName;
```

I'm surprised that line was not giving a compile time error.  However, since you have not elaborated on what type of class customer is, nor what custName means, it's hard to give a definitive on what is going on here.  I assume that customer is an instance of a custom class you built and that custName is string property on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. It is not working even if I write baseUrl as "+baseUrl+" in window.open command. 
 If I am writing my url directly in window.open command (with concatenation operator), it is giving me compile time error.

Comment: What ist he compile time error?  And show the line of code that the error occurs on.

Comment: It worked! actually baseURL should be passes as

           [' "+baseURL+ " ']  It needs single quotes too. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @javaIQ Great; be sure to mark this as the correct answer using the 'checkmark' button next to the voting box.